# Derive Cauchy-Bunyakovsky by taking expected value

Tags: probability, inequality

In my notes, it is said that taking expectation on both sides of this inequality $$|\frac{XY}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}X^2\mathbb{E}Y^2}}|\le\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{X^2}{\mathbb{E}X^2}+\frac{Y^2}{\mathbb{E}Y^2}\right)$$ can lead to the Cauchy-Bunyakovxky (Schwarz) inequality $$\mathbb{E}|XY|\le\sqrt{\mathbb{E}X^2\mathbb{E}Y^2}$$ I am not really good at taking expected values, may anyone guide me how to go about it?

Note: I am familiar with the linearity and monotonicity of expected values, what I am unsure about is the derivation that leads to the inequality, especially when dealing with double expectation.

Thanks.

Comment: About double expectation: When you take expectation once, it became a constant - so you can use linearity to pull out the constant when you have a second expectation. As an example, $\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{X^2}{\mathbb{E}X^2}\right) \stackrel{linearity}{=} \frac{1}{ \mathbb{E}X^2} \mathbb{E}X^2 = 1$.

Comment: @Sanchez yup you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your inequality as follows, for the left side:

$|\frac {XY}{\sqrt{EX^{2}EY^{2}}}|=\frac {|XY|}{\sqrt{EX^{2}EY^{2}}}$

for the right side, take the expectation:

$\frac{1}{2}E\left( \frac{X^2}{EX^2}+\frac{Y^2}{EY^2}\right)= \frac{1}{2} E \left( \frac{X^2 EY^2+X^2 EY^2}{EY^2 EX^2} \right)$

Now, $E(X^2 EY^2+X^2 EY^2)=2*EX^2EY^2 $ using the fact that $E(EY^2)=E(Y^2)$

Plug in and you get the result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** All you need to know here is that expected value is linear, i.e. for arbitrary random variables $X,Y$ and all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ $$\mathbb{E}(aX+bY)=a\mathbb{E}X +b\mathbb{E}Y.$$
Is this a fact you are familiar with?

---

Monotonicity is also important. Once you have $X\le Y$, then you also know that $\mathbb{E}X\le\mathbb{E}Y.$ This is exactly the case you are dealing with. For now, you have that one random variable (namely $\frac{\vert XY\vert}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}X^2\mathbb{E}Y^2}}$) is not greater than the other. If you take the expected value of both sides then the inequality will remain true. It will be essentially the Cauchy-Schwarz you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Kuba. I am familiar with linearity and monotonicity of expected value. What I am struggling with is the derivation that leads to the Cauchy inequality. If we take expected values, then there will be double expected value, how are we supposed to do with that?

Comment: You need to remember that denominators in your inequality are just numbers, so they play a role of $a,b$ - the multipliers which you can just pull out of expectation.

Comment: ah yes. How careless I am to not have noticed that. Thanks very much.

Comment: You are welcome.